# Overlapping UITextView border

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiinterfaceorientation

I need to support Landscape and Portrait orientation for my app, and I venture into using a single UIView.

When I first simulate the application, it displays the result without a problem. However, when I change orientation to landscape, the problem occurs.

The first time I run the application in portrait:
[image]

When I change the orientation to landscape:
[image]
Notice the lower left corner, near the Information tab.

When I change back the orientation to portrait:
[image]
It gets worse.

The code I am using,

```
- (void)updateLayoutForNewOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]);
    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]);

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        NSLog(@"Portrait");
        [self iPhoneUserInterfacePortrait:width height:height];
    }

    else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        NSLog(@"Landscape");
        [self iPhoneUserInterfaceLandscape:width height:height];
    }
}

- (void)iPhoneUserInterfacePortrait:(CGFloat)width height:(CGFloat)height
{
    UITextView *descriptionTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width - 100.0, height - 300.0)];

    [self makeBorder:descriptionTextView];
    [self setInformation:descriptionTextView];
    [self.view addSubview:descriptionTextView];
}

- (void)iPhoneUserInterfaceLandscape:(CGFloat)width height:(CGFloat)height
{
    UITextView *descriptionTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width + 230, height - 368.0)];

    [self makeBorder:descriptionTextView];
    [self setInformation:descriptionTextView];
    [self.view addSubview:descriptionTextView];
}

- (void)makeBorder:(UITextView *)descriptionTextView
{
    descriptionTextView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0;
    descriptionTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
    descriptionTextView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];

    [self.view addSubview:descriptionTextView];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding several views while you want just one.

```
[self.view addSubview:descriptionTextView];
```

To get rid of this line, you could add field `descriptionTextView` to your ViewController subclass and change frame of that text view without adding/removing it from `self.view`.
Also you should try to play with AutoResizing masks to see if you can get needed results without actually changing frame manually.
And you should be careful with that constants: try your app on both 3.5 and 4.0 inch simulator devices.